# Android db onUpgrade doesn't work in release mode

Tags: android, database, upgrade

I am experiencing strange behaviour during onUpgrade inside my DatabaseHelper class. I changed database version and it is working as expected when I am in debug mode (onUpgrade was called and update went well).

But when I exported signed apk and uploaded it to market it doesn't work.

Can any body suggest what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: trace your program and see what is executed and what is not during the update.

Comment: I can reproduce such behaviour by installing signed apk using adb tool. But how can I debug it? onUpgrade is simply not called. What should I trace?

Comment: or look at the code of sdk on grepcode and find out why it is no called.

Comment: same problem have you found solution?

Answer (score 0):

did you remove the debug version prior to installing the signed one ? (on your android device)

Comment: i dont think its possible to install signed one on a debug version. It conflicts

Comment: yes I unistalled it. Users that has only release version (downloaded from market) also experience problems with update :(